# Trying to Reconcile/refresh terraform infrastructure drift

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

I have a Terraform GCE resource being created using the following module:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "gke_proxy1" {
  ...
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "gke_proxy1" {
  ...
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "gke_proxy1" {
  ...
}
```

However at some point, outside Terraform scripts, created the google_compute_address for a specific GCE already so when I try and apply the TF script, it tries to create the compute address which is not what I want.
For e.g. using:

```
terraform plan -var "env=dev" -target module.gke-proxy-primary;
```

If I run the following to show real-world state :

```
 terraform state show module.gke-proxy-primary.google_compute_instance.gke_proxy1
```

Output shows the expected compute_address state address as expected:

```
network_interface {                                                                                                                                                             
     name               = "nic0"                                                                                                                                                 
     ...                                                                                                             
 }                                                                                                                                                                               
 network_interface {                                                                                                                                                             
     name               = "nic1"                                                                                                                                                 
     ...                                                                                                             
 }
```

So I guess I need rebuild the TF state from the real-world infra so I have tried the following since there's been a drift between state and real world:
Running  :

```
terraform refresh -var "env=dev" -target module.gke-proxy-primary;
```

Gives me :

```
module.gke-proxy-primary.google_compute_disk.gke_proxy1: Refreshing state... [id=projects/proj1/zones/europe-west2-a/disks/gke-proxy1]
module.gke-proxy-primary.google_compute_instance.gke_proxy1: Refreshing state... [id=projects/proj1/zones/europe-west2-a/instances/gke-proxy1]
```

So it's not refreshing the compute_address.gke_proxy1 remote bucket state for the resource as expected from real world.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html

Comment: @marco.m thanks, this was what I needed to do as I needed to just import the compute_address resource.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the missing dependency compute_address to state for the main resource gce using:

   terraform import  -var "env=dev" -var "primary_cluster_suffix=1" module.gke-proxy-primary.google_compute_address.gke_proxy1 hsbc-10723777-safe-dev/europe-west2/gke-proxy1
2. Verify the resource is then in the local state:

   terraform state show module.gke-proxy-primary.google_compute_address.gke_proxy1
   It should now show.
3. Run plan and it should reconcile as expected.